# Mousemove / scroll to next hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I added the following code in order to scroll with my mouse (scroll on click+drag, not by the mousewheel). So far, so good -  works like a charm:

```
var clicked = false, clickY;
$(document).on({
'mousemove': function(e) {
    clicked && updateScrollPos(e);
},
'mousedown': function(e) {
    clicked = true;
    clickY = e.pageY;
},
'mouseup': function() {
    clicked = false;
    $('html').css('cursor', 'auto');
}
});

var updateScrollPos = function(e) {
    $('html').css('cursor', 'row-resize');
    $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + (clickY - e.pageY));
}
```

I am trying to change this scroll behavior so that each directional click+drag mouse movement jumps to the next/closest hash after e.g. a 10px drag. In other words, a mouse scroll up should jump to the next hash above the current position, scrolling down should jump to the next one below.

This doesn't seem to be covered by any of the related questions.

> > Edit:

I think I need to replace

```
$(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + (clickY - e.pageY));
```

by parts of the solution in the link that follows. Unfortunately, this seems to be above my skill level:

[how to get nearest anchor from the current mouse position on mouse move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42852872/how-to-get-nearest-anchor-from-the-current-mouse-position-on-mouse-move)

> > Solution:

I used Saeed Ataee's answer, really happy about that code, but replaced the mouse-wheel code portion with the following one I had in place already, just happened to work better on my end (I am sure his is fine, just giving an alternative here):

```
$('#nav').onePageNav();


var $current, flag = false;

$('body').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
if (flag) { return false; }
$current = $('div.current');

if (delta > 0) {
    $prev = $current.prev();

    if ($prev.length) {
        flag = true;
        $('body').scrollTo($prev, 1000, {
            onAfter : function(){
                flag = false;
            }
        });
        $current.removeClass('current');
        $prev.addClass('current');
    }
} else {
    $next = $current.next();

    if ($next.length) {
        flag = true;
        $('body').scrollTo($next, 1000, {
            onAfter : function(){
                flag = false;
            }
        });
        $current.removeClass('current');
        $next.addClass('current');
    }
}

event.preventDefault();
```

});

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scroll HTML page to given anchor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor)

Comment: Thanks for the input, but it isn't a duplicate in my opinion at all, even though it might contain helpful code. What I am trying to do here is rewrite my mouse click scroll behavior to scroll to a hash rather than just scroll up and down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is your answer.

```js
let currentElement = 0,
  maxLength = $("div[id^='section']").length,
  changeSw = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
  var clicked = false,
    clickY;
  $(document).on({
    mousemove: function(e) {
      clicked && updateScrollPos(e);
    },
    mousedown: function(e) {
      clicked = true;
      changeSw = true;
      clickY = e.pageY;
    },
    mouseup: function() {
      clicked = false;
      changeSw = false;
      $("html").css("cursor", "auto");
    }
  });

  var updateScrollPos = function(e) {
    $("html").css("cursor", "row-resize");
    // $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + (clickY - e.pageY));
    if (changeSw && clickY - e.pageY > 0) {
      currentElement =
        (currentElement < maxLength - 1) ? currentElement + 1 : currentElement;
      changeSw = false;
      clicked = false;
    } else if (changeSw && clickY - e.pageY <= 0) {
      currentElement = currentElement > 0 ? currentElement - 1 : 0;
      changeSw = false;
      clicked = false;
    }
    console.log(currentElement)
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#section-" + currentElement).offset().top
      },
      200
    );

  };

  $(document).on("mousewheel", function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
      currentElement = currentElement > 0 ? currentElement - 1 : 0;

      $("html, body").animate({
          scrollTop: $("#section-" + currentElement).offset().top
        },
        200
      );
    } else {
      currentElement =
        currentElement < maxLength - 1 ? currentElement + 1 : currentElement;
      $("html, body").animate({
          scrollTop: $("#section-" + currentElement).offset().top
        },
        200
      );
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="section-0">Section 1</div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="section-1">Section 2</div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="section-2">Section 3</div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="section-3">Section 4</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. The mouse-wheel code I had in place worked better for me, but the rest is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much! I added the mouse-wheel code to my question in case you wanna check it out.

Comment: How would I add a condition that requires a minimum drag of, let's say, 100px in either direction before the jump gets triggered?

Comment: I think changing `clickY - e.pageY > 0` to `clickY - e.pageY > 100` solve that. Check it. Good luck.

Comment: That's not it, but I'll try to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I hope this helps you

```js
let currentElement = 0,
  maxLength = $("div[id^='section']").length;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("mousewheel", function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
      currentElement = (currentElement > 0) ? currentElement - 1 : 0;

      $("html, body").animate({
          scrollTop: $("#section-" + currentElement).offset().top
        },
        200
      );
    } else {
      currentElement = (currentElement < maxLength - 1) ? currentElement + 1 : currentElement;
      $("html, body").animate({
          scrollTop: $("#section-" + currentElement).offset().top
        },
        200
      );
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="section-0">Section 1</div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="section-1">Section 2</div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="section-2">Section 3</div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="section-3">Section 4</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Great code, but not what I was looking for. I got this functionality plus the one I posted in my question alerady in place. What I am trying to do is to modify the code I included in my question to jump to the next hash on click+drag, rather than just scroll a few pixels up.

Comment: The Drag and Move is indeed what I need, thanks! Ideally I would like to add that last bit into my existing code rather than replacing all by this fullPage code.

Answer (score 2):

I see a few things you have to solve:

**1) Mark and find which elements you want to scroll to**

Put something like an ID attribute or class on the elements you'd like to scroll to. With the ID attribute you can use the old fashioned hash URL navigation (http://some-url/#some-anchor) in addition to your new method to navigate.

Let's say you use the format `#scroll-to-A`, `#scroll-to-B`, etc. as IDs for your anchors. You can then target all elements with an ID containing the string `scroll-to` using [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with this:

`const scrollElements = document.querySelectorAll("[id*='scroll-to']");`.

> `querySelectorAll` does not return an Element array, but a
>   NodeList. You can convert it into an array using
>   `Array.from(scrollElements)`. It can be useful to know for the rest of the code I'm presenting.

**2) Given any vertical scroll position on the page, find which element should be scrolled into view next**

Using [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) you can determine how many pixels from the top of the screen an element is positioned:

```
function getTopPositionForElement(el) {
    return el.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY;
}
```

Then you can calculate which element to scroll to next by checking which is closest to the top of the page. 
Use `Array.sort` to determine which is closest in the array and then choose the first element in the list:

```
function calculateNextElement(direction) {
    // Handle the cases for direction here...

    switch (direction) {
        case "down": 
            return scrollElements.sort((a, b) => { 
                return getTopPositionForElement(a) > getTopPositionForElement(b) ? -1 : 1;
            })[0];
        case "up":
            // Fill in here
        default: 
            // Fill in here
    }
}
```

> One thing you have to add here is handling the two cases of which
>   direction the user is scrolling. This implementation only takes into
>   account the downward scrolling. [Maybe this can help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223341/detecting-scroll-direction/31223774)

**3) Scroll element into view**

Using [`Element.scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) you can scroll the element into view so that it is visible to the user. I chose to add "smooth" scrolling below, but you can use other options. Check the documentation.

```
function scrollElementIntoView(direction) {
    const next = calculateNextElement(direction);
    next.scrollIntoView({
        behaviour: "smooth"
    });
}
```

**4) Capture vertical swipe mouse movements**

This one seems a bit tricky. You could use something like [HammerJS](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/) if you are comfortable using a library.

Essentially what it comes down to is capturing the mouse on `mousedown` and then again on `mouseup`, checking how many pixels the mouse has moved between the two events. I would also suggest checking the movement speed between the two points.

Here is an attempt:

```
let previousEvent;
let time;

// Keep track of the position where the user starts dragging
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
    previousEvent = event;
    time = new Date();
});

// When the mouse is released, figure out which direction the mouse went
document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
    const pixelsY = previousEvent.screenY - event.screenY;
    const timeTaken = Date.now() - time.getTime();
    const speed = pixelsY / timeTaken;

    let direction;
    if (speed > 1) {
        direction = "up";
    } else if (speed < -1) {
        direction = "down";
    } else {
        direction = "tap";
    }

    scrollElementIntoView(direction);
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: The snipped of the questions allows to click and drag in any direction (a few px up or down). I am trying to get an automatic jump to the nearest hash/section to the bottom when the listener notices a click and a scrolling down behavior and an automatic jump to the nearest hash/section to the top when there is a click with an upwards scroll movement. Any idea how to rewrite your code to achieve that? Or does your code do just that I am failing to implement it correctly?

Comment: The code I've written down does not do that. However, I think I've given you most of the pieces to the puzzles. You should be able to figure it out :)

Comment: Your code by itself doesn't take any drag behavior into account, right? It's also written in JS while the snipped above is JQuery. i am still pretty beginner and even though I understand what your code does, I am not able to rewrite the original snipped to JS.

Comment: Oh okay. You mean something similar to how you flick the screen on your mobile device when you want to scroll? For that you'd need to extend the functionality of your mouse listener.

Comment: Exactly. I got already code in place (before the answer above was posted) that jumps to the next hash on mousewheel trigger. On top of that, I added the code I posted above that allows to click and drag with the mouse. I want to click>hold>drag in a direction>"jump to next hash after 10px of drag". I thought it was possible to modify the mousemove behavior in order to account for this.

Comment: I added a link to my question that seems to provide useful code. Maybe you can find the time to look into it, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Added another section to my answer, covering swipe mouse motions.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I decided to go with Saeed's answer, but learned a bunch from your post. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cool dude :) happy to help