# Make menu hamburger close when click on link and outside

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a simple hamburger menu for my site, I just can not get it to close after clicking on a link and going to the anchor that I put in and that also closes when I click off the menu.

My HTML is:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navbar-fostrap').click(function() {
      $('.nav-fostrap').toggleClass('visible');
      $('body').toggleClass('cover-bg');
    });
  });
```

```css
nav {
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: width:100%;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 100000;
}

.navbar-default {
  transition: 500ms ease;
  background: transparent;
}

.navbar-default.scrolled {
  background: rgba(28, 28, 28, 0.8);
}

a.title {
  float: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  font-family: quantum;
  height: 55px;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

.title {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  height: 55px;
}

.nav-fostrap ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: auto;
}

.nav-fostrap ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 0;
  list-style: none;
  height: 60px;
}

a.menu {
  font-family: Montserrat, Arial;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px 0;
  margin-top: 14.5px;
  margin-bottom: 10.5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 40px;
  top: -10px;
}

a:hover.menu {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a:before,
a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  background: #fff;
}

.menu a:before {
  left: 0;
}

.menu a:after {
  right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  transition: width 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.61, 0.36, 1);
}

.menu a:hover:before {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.61, 0.36, 1);
}

.menu a:hover:after {
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0s;
}

.title-on-mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
  a.title {
    float: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
    font-family: quantum;
    height: 55px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: -50px;
  }
  .nav-fostrap {
    background: #1c1c1c;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: -200px;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.25s ease;
    -moz-transition: left 0.25s ease;
    -ms-transition: left 0.25s ease;
    -o-transition: left 0.25s ease;
    transition: left 0.25s ease;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 105;
  }
  .nav-fostrap.visible {
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.25s ease;
    -moz-transition: left 0.25s ease;
    -ms-transition: left 0.25s ease;
    -o-transition: left 0.25s ease;
    transition: left 0.25s ease;
    z-index: 90;
  }
  .nav-bg-fostrap {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: transperant;
    padding: 12px 0 0 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    z-index: 100;
  }
  .navbar-fostrap {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 12px;
    z-index: 102;
  }
  .navbar-fostrap span {
    height: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-fostrap span:nth-child(2) {
    width: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-fostrap span:nth-child(3) {
    width: 20px;
  }
  .nav-fostrap ul {
    padding-top: 50px;
  }
  .nav-fostrap li {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-fostrap li a {
    display: block;
    color: #505050;
    font-weight: 600;
  }
  .nav-fostrap li:first-child:hover a {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .cover-bg {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="headercontainer">
    <a class="title" href="#seccao-inicio"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" width="80" href="#" style="position: relative;margin-left: 12px; float:right; top:2.5px;position: relative;" /></a>

    <div class='nav-fostrap'>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a class="menu" href="#seccao-historia" style="color: white;">História</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#seccao-network" style="color: white;">Network</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#seccao-fundadores" style="color: white;">Fundadores</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="contacto.html" style="color: white;">Contacto</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='nav-bg-fostrap'>
      <div class='navbar-fostrap'> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I am developing this site for a professional aptitude project of my course so any help was welcome. If anyone could help me I was very grateful, thank you.

Comment: If you combine all those snippets into one in the `<>` editor then we could run that code here in page and see it in action. By separating them into three snippets the css and js is not associated with the html in order to work together when clicking on *"Run code snippet"*

Comment: Check my answer, I update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this part of code and also add any other logic you want.

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    if (
      !$(target).is(".navbar-fostrap") &&
      !$(target).parents(".navbar-fostrap").length &&
      !$(target).parents(".nav-fostrap").length
    ) {
      $(".nav-fostrap").removeClass("visible");
      $("body").removeClass("cover-bg");
    }
});
```

Full code here

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".navbar-fostrap").click(function() {
    $(".nav-fostrap").toggleClass("visible");
    $("body").toggleClass("cover-bg");
  });
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    if (!$(target).is(".navbar-fostrap") &&
      !$(target).parents(".navbar-fostrap").length &&
      !$(target).parents(".nav-fostrap").length
    ) {
      $(".nav-fostrap").removeClass("visible");
      $("body").removeClass("cover-bg");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}

nav {
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: width:100%;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 100000;
}

.navbar-default {
  transition: 500ms ease;
  background: transparent;
}

.navbar-default.scrolled {
  background: rgba(28, 28, 28, 0.8);
}

a.title {
  float: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  font-family: quantum;
  height: 55px;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

.title {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  height: 55px;
}

.nav-fostrap ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: auto;
}

.nav-fostrap ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 0;
  list-style: none;
  height: 60px;
}

a.menu {
  font-family: Montserrat, Arial;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px 0;
  margin-top: 14.5px;
  margin-bottom: 10.5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 40px;
  top: -10px;
}

a:hover.menu {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a:before,
a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  background: #fff;
}

.menu a:before {
  left: 0;
}

.menu a:after {
  right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  transition: width 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.61, 0.36, 1);
}

.menu a:hover:before {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.61, 0.36, 1);
}

.menu a:hover:after {
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0s;
}

.title-on-mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
  a.title {
    float: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
    font-family: quantum;
    height: 55px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: -50px;
  }
  .nav-fostrap {
    background: #1c1c1c;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: -200px;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.25s ease;
    -moz-transition: left 0.25s ease;
    -ms-transition: left 0.25s ease;
    -o-transition: left 0.25s ease;
    transition: left 0.25s ease;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 105;
  }
  .nav-fostrap.visible {
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.25s ease;
    -moz-transition: left 0.25s ease;
    -ms-transition: left 0.25s ease;
    -o-transition: left 0.25s ease;
    transition: left 0.25s ease;
    z-index: 90;
  }
  .nav-bg-fostrap {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: transperant;
    padding: 12px 0 0 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    z-index: 100;
  }
  .navbar-fostrap {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 12px;
    z-index: 102;
  }
  .navbar-fostrap span {
    height: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-fostrap span:nth-child(2) {
    width: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-fostrap span:nth-child(3) {
    width: 20px;
  }
  .nav-fostrap ul {
    padding-top: 50px;
  }
  .nav-fostrap li {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-fostrap li a {
    display: block;
    color: #505050;
    font-weight: 600;
  }
  .nav-fostrap li:first-child:hover a {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .cover-bg {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="menu navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="headercontainer">
    <a class="title" href="#seccao-inicio"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" width="80" href="#" style="position: relative;margin-left: 12px; float:right; top:2.5px;position: relative;" /></a>

    <div class='nav-fostrap'>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a class="menu" href="#seccao-historia" style="color: white;">História</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#seccao-network" style="color: white;">Network</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#seccao-fundadores" style="color: white;">Fundadores</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="contacto.html" style="color: white;">Contacto</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='nav-bg-fostrap'>
      <div class='navbar-fostrap'> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Uau thanks a lot! :D Just one more thing if possible, you can put the menu when it opens to not return to the top of the site and when I click on a menu item for example the "Founders" it closes and makes a smooth scroll. You can see the example here, thank you. http://quantumn.atwebpages.com/

Comment: Read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297599/mousemove-scroll-to-next-hash/50343728#50343728) I answer it there. If it does not help, ask me @KR4K

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help I just wanted it when I clicked on the menu it did not go back to the top and when I click on the link it closes itself so I do not have to click to close it and only then to scroll to the section that I defined.

Comment: Ok. give me time. can you provide a working exampe on plunker or codepen?? @KR4K

Comment: CodePen if its possible. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Yes it is here. The only link that really works is História, in this example. https://codepen.io/Pro90_PT/pen/pKJjQX

Comment: Omg worked, very thankful that was it! But only one thing that part of the code has changed? CSS, HTML OR JS?

Comment: Look at js part. I also put codes for closing navbar in `a` click @KR4K

Comment: Yes, I have, thank you. But how can I stop him from returning to the top when I click to open the menu?

Comment: Okay, when you change, please comment. Thanks for all the help. But until it's working so hard.

Comment: Check it again! I changed it. @KR4K

Comment: Nice its great now! Thanks for helping me! :D

Comment: Only one thing I know I'm annoying that I do not talk a bit but as I saw you're a king of JavaScript you can take a look at this my other project yesterday hear a user who helped me only have a problem I did not want it when this refresh the news with the tags change of place type as if a random mode was on. You can see it here if you do not mind. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50568350/make-recent-posts-label-box-using-li-childs-javascript/50569116?noredirect=1#comment88191628_50569116